# Обработка динамического атрибута полей формы - name

Tags: php

Есть форма, которая имеет `name="header1%РАНДОМНОЕ ЧИСЛО%"`. Так вот, как обработать запрос на PHP, если не знаем рандомного числа?
Если бы его не было, делал так:
`if(isset($_POST['header1']))`

А с этим как? Мб подобрать регулярное выражение типа `header1[любое число]`

UPD: Сделал через скрытый input

Comment: id в PHP недоступен.

Comment: тов. Ипатьев хочет сказать, что ключами для значений  в запросе служат атрибуты `name`

Comment: не понял, а как `id` формы вообще может в PHP оказаться? `id`  в `$_POST` вообще никак не попадает. `name` только

Comment: не совсем понятно. зачем вам рандомное число? почему вы не можете использовать массив? `name="header[]"`? В этом случае будет не важно сколько у Вас полей с такими вот именами. `$_POST["header"]` будет представлять из себя php массив.